# How to prove $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\sin(n)| = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, limsup-and-liminf, decimal-expansion

Does decimal expansion of $\pi$ contain blocks of zeroes of any integer length? I.e. $0$, $00$, $000$, $\ldots$

I discovered this question, when trying to prove $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\sin(n)| = 1.$$
Or is there any idea how to find subsequence $k_n$ such that $\sin(k_n) \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that would imply that $\pi$ is normal, but that has not been proven.

Comment: That is, simply, not known

Comment: @EemilWallin Why would that imply that $\pi$ was normal? The number $0.1010010001000001000001\dots$ is certainly not normal.

Comment: Given _any_ finite string of numbers, it is most likely to be somewhere in the expansion of $\pi$ (the probability of it happening, given that the expansion of $\pi$ is psuedo-random, is $1$), but we do not know whether it's always the case.

Comment: I don't get how knowing anything about the decimal expansion of $\pi$ could help to prove $\limsup_n |\sin n| = 1$.

Comment: If $\pi$ is multiplied by power of $10$, the block of zeroes can be shiftet right behind the decimal point. Then can be found $n$ and $k$ (power of 10) such that $|n-k\frac{\pi}{2}|$ is small.

Comment: @joseph Consider the approximations of $\pi /2$ given by the continued fraction of $\pi /2$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks I'll try..

Comment: In general, truncated continued fractions give you (always) better approximations than truncated decimal expansion. You don't even need to compute them, since you know that they are good enough. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) for details.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem:)

Comment: Some related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438636/proof-of-limsup-sin-nx-1-n-rightarrow-infty-forall-x-in-mathbbr (You can find also other questions linked there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183502433), a special case is that there is two increasing sequences of odd positive integers $(p_n),(q_n)$ such that $$ \left|\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| \leq  \frac{1}{q_n^2},\quad n>1.$$

Note that $\sin |x| = |\sin x |$ for $x\in [0,\pi]$, then 
$$\sin \left|\frac{q_n\pi }{2} - p_n\right|= \left|\cos p_n\right| <\frac{1}{q_n} \to 0.$$
therefore $|\sin p_n|\to 1$.