# The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n} x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title saying , the question is how to find the   radius  $R$ of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n} x^n$. My method is as the following:

When $x=1$, it is well known that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}$ is convergent by Dirichlet's test, and so is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\sin n}{n}$ . when $x>1$, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin n}{n} x^n $ does not exist. Therefore, if $x>1$, the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n} x^n$ is not convergent. So $R=1$. Is this solution right? or is there any other method to calculate the radius?

I would appreciate if someone could give some suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

If for a given power series $\Sigma_0^{\infty} a_nx^n$ we have $\alpha=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|{a_n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} $ then the radius of convergence is defined as $R=\frac{1}{\alpha}$

Here we have $R=\frac{1}{\limsup{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{sin(n)}{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$

Comment: And why does this show $R=1$?

Comment: the limsup for this sequence is achieved if we take a subsequence of integers such that sin(n)=1 and n^{1/n} tends to 1 as n goes to infinity

Comment: not quite: surely you don't mean $\sin(n)=1$ for integer $n$? I found a proof but it's not immediate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721909

Comment: ok sorry maybe we'll have to take a sequence such that sin(n) goes to 1

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. You can't use the Ratio Test or the Root Test profitably here, but you've found $R$ such that the series converges at $\pm R$, the series clearly converges for $|x|<R$ by comparison to the geometric series, and can't possibly converge beyond it as it fails the Test for Divergence. Hence the radius of convergence is $R$.